# Updating dynamoDB from Lambda function failed

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, alexa-skills-kit

I've got a problem updating DynamoDB entry.

The DB looks like this

```
{
   "userId":"amzn1.ask.account.XYZ",
   "mapAttr":{
      "name":"John",
      "colors":[
         "yellow",
         "white"
      ]
   }
}
```

I want to update the List of colors utilizing follwoing code:

```
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ apiVersion: "2012-08-10" });
var params = {
  TableName: "myTable",

  Key: {
    userId: userId
  },
  UpdateExpression: "SET #mapAttr = list_append(#mapAttr, :entry)",

  ExpressionAttributeNames: { "#mapAttr": "mapAttr.colors" },

  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ":entry": ["blue"]
  },

  ReturnValues: "UPDATED_NEW"
};

docClient.update(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(
      "Unable to update item. Error JSON:",
      JSON.stringify(err, null, 2)
    );
  } else {
    console.log("UpdateItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
  }
});
```

and i get the following message:

> Unable to update item. Error JSON: {   "message": "The provided key
>   element does not match the schema",   "code": "ValidationException",

Any ideas why... ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cant update Dynamo Db table , getting ValidationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40661334/cant-update-dynamo-db-table-getting-validationexception)

Comment: Try "SET #mapAttr.#colors " and add the "#colors" attribute to the ExpressionAttributeNames.

Comment: It is for sure not a duplicate. In the aforementioned link someone had a problem updating single item column, whereas i need a solution to update a List type attribute called colors in the column mapAttr, which alone is an attribute object.

Comment: Found a solution yet?

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Answer (score 0):

Per [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.SET.AddingNestedMapAttributes), you need to split your `ExpressionAttributeNames` up.

```
UpdateExpression: "SET #mapAttr.#colors = list_append(#mapAttr.#colors, :entry)",
ExpressionAttributeNames: { 
    "#mapAttr": "mapAttr", 
    "#colors": "colors"
}
```